# ASP 5 MVC 6 - Pros and cons: multiple web api services - use one or more projects?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to migrate my `WCF` services to `Web API / MVC6`.

Currently I have one application hosting multiple WCF web services (`http://{ip}/{app}/Service{x}.svc/{vs_endpoint}`). This model is pretty good, we can separate the public services from internal services and we have control over each service in particular, although they all are under one single application.

Would I be able to achieve similar thing in `Web API / MVC6`, having one project for multiple services? From my initial investigations I understood I would need to do something along [these lines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/03/07/asp-net-web-api-using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis/).

If yes, it would be nice to have some recommendations how to structure this project.

Also, can you share some pros and cons about one vs multiple projects to host these services?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check this https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html

Comment: You can use `Areas` too...http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-area-in-mvc-5/

Comment: Web API is so much better than regular WCF. Just go for it. And if you start a new project you can use new ASP.NET Core for your Web API project. It was recently released.

Comment: Thanks Hackerman, at least now I understood the use of `Areas` :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this by using either separate controllers or logically grouping controllers into areas.
Once you start programming you will automatically came to know that how it is possible and easier to do than wcf.
good luck...